# No attributes auto-complete in Netbeans after register the custom component in .taglib.xml

Tags: jsf, netbeans, jsf-2, custom-component, taglib

I create a custom component for `SelectOneRadio`, and I register it in `xyz.taglib.xml` and so far it works. The only problem is that my NetBeans cannot see my tag attribute in auto-complete. For example, if I have `layout="pageDirection"` in my custom component, then it render correctly, but when I (Ctrl + space) I do not see `layout`, `value` ... attributes. Here is how I register my custom component in my `WEB-INF/faces-config.xml`, I have

```
<component>
    <component-type>com.xyz.om.ui.component.SelectOneRadio</component-type>
    <component-class>
        com.xyz.om.ui.component.SelectOneRadio
    </component-class>
    <component-extension>
        <component-family>com.xyz.om.ui.component.SelectOneRadio</component-family>
        <renderer-type>com.xyz.om.ui.renderer.SelectOneRadioRenderer</renderer-type>
    </component-extension>
</component>
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>com.xyz.om.ui.component.SelectOneRadio</component-family>
        <renderer-type>com.xyz.om.ui.renderer.SelectOneRadioRenderer</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>
            com.xyz.om.ui.renderer.SelectOneRadioRenderer
        </renderer-class>    
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

In my `WEB-INF/xyz.taglib.xml`, I have

```
<facelet-taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
            version="2.0">
<namespace>http://example.com/ui</namespace>
<tag>
    <tag-name>selectOneRadio</tag-name>
    <component>
        <component-type>com.xyz.om.ui.component.SelectOneRadio</component-type>
        <renderer-type>com.xyz.om.ui.renderer.SelectOneRadioRenderer</renderer-type>            
    </component>
</tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

so I register the `xyz.taglib.xml` in `web.xml` as follow

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/xyz.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

After this steps, if I Ctrl + space (Netbeans) on the custom component, I can only see `class, id, parent , rendered, rendererType, transient`. So I try create a `xyz.tld` under WEB-INF, like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd">
<tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
<short-name>xyz</short-name>
<uri>http://example.com/ui</uri>

<tag>       
    <name>selectOneRadio</name>
    <tag-class>com.xyz.om.ui.tag.SelectOneRadioTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>JSP</body-content>
    <attribute>
        <description>
            xyz description
        </description>
        <name>name</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <deferred-value>
            <type>java.lang.String</type>
        </deferred-value>         

    </attribute>
</tag>
</taglib>
```

but still the `name` attribute does not show in netbeans when I write out the tag. **I guess my question is how to get netbeans to auto-complete my custom component's attributes, because everything works, but no auto-complete is a pain**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The attributes are autocompleted based on the `.taglib.xml` file. You need to register every individual attribute in the `<tag>` element.

```
<tag>
    <tag-name>selectOneRadio</tag-name>
    <component>
        <component-type>com.xyz.om.ui.component.SelectOneRadio</component-type>
        <renderer-type>com.xyz.om.ui.renderer.SelectOneRadioRenderer</renderer-type>            
    </component>
    <attribute>
        <name>id</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <type>java.lang.String</type>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>binding</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <type>javax.faces.component.UIComponent</type>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>rendered</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <type>java.lang.Boolean</type>
    </attribute>
    <!-- Etc.. -->
</tag>
```

The `.tld` is only mandatory when you plan to support JSP next to Facelets as well. Note that JSF 2.0 itself doesn't support JSP, it'll run in JSF 1.2 fallback modus.

Comment: I am currently in a similar situation. I am extending HtmlCommandButton and added a tag-attribute. I have a taglib that has the additional attribute but on autocomplete I dont get the inherited attributes. Do I have to add all attributes that I inherit to the taglib as well? THis would be very tedious.